# System.InvalidOperationException: "The model backing the 'Connection' context has changed since the database was created

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, table

Мне нужно, что бы при регистрации каждого нового пользователя, создавалась таблица, которая бы называлась как логин пользователя

```
public class Connection : DbContext

{
    public string CurrentLogin { get; set; }
    public Connection() : base("LinkConnectionString")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Word> Words { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Word>().ToTable(CurrentLogin);

   }

}
```

Выдает ошибку

System.InvalidOperationException: "The model backing the 'Connection' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)."

на строке

connection.Users.Add(user);

```
            string loginString = LoginEnter.Text;
            string passwordString = PasswordEnter.Text;

            using (Connection connection = new Connection())
            {   

                connection.CurrentLogin = loginString;

                User user = new User()
                {
                    Login = loginString,
                    Password = passwordString
                };

                connection.Users.Add(user);
                connection.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: Ошибка явно оговорит о том, что модель изменилась, а структура БД устарела. Вам надо создать новую миграцию и обновить БД.

Comment: Как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: Какой подход вы используете? Code-First или Database-First? Если Code-First, то у вас явно проблемы, так как БД была изменена без миграций или вы изменили контекст, а миграцию накатить забыли. Если Database-First, то как вы сгенерировали классы контекста? Вам надо их перегенерировать.

Comment: `что бы при регистрации каждого нового пользователя, создавалась таблица` Таблица или запись в таблице?

Comment: @tym32167 Таблица. Code-First, я только начинаю в этом разбираться, так что пока не особо понимаю, что такое миграция

Comment: Entity Framework не позволяет создавать новые таблицы. Вы только можете читать и писать в существующие таблицы. Если вы хотите менять схему БД во время работы приложения, вам надо использовать что то более низкоуровневое, например чистый ado.net - sqlcommand и прочее. Но я бы начал с вопроса - зачем создавать новые таблицы для нового юзера?

Comment: @tym32167 Я делаю что-то типа переводчика. Мне нужно, что бы для каждого пользователя хранились слова и перевод к ним, например table - стол, chair - стул.

Comment: Для этого нужна таблица с переводами, нет необходимости срздавать отдельную таблицу для каждого юзера.

Comment: @tym32167 Я кажется понял, спасибо

Comment: Вам вполне достаточно сделать таблицу в которой (помимо первичного ключа) были поля Word, Translation и OwnerId (внешний ключ к таблице пользователей)